# Why does this work to shift a power series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

**Problem**: Find the Taylor series and the interval on which it is valid for
$f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$
centered around $x=5$.

The **textbook's solution** says to write
$$\frac{1}{1-x} = \frac{1}{-4-(x-5)} = -\frac 14 \cdot \frac{1}{1-\left(-\frac{x-5}{4}\right)} \\
     = -\frac 14 \cdot \sum_{n \geq 0} \left(-\frac{x-5}{4}\right)^n
    = -\frac 14 \cdot \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{(-1)^n}{4^n}(x-5)^n \\
   = \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{4^{n+1}}(x-5)^n.$$
I understand each of the individual steps (they're not exactly difficult) and this is the same answer I get if I create the series from scratch (using the Taylor series definition), but this solution is raising several issues

1) *What is this doing?* I mean, why/how is this "shifting the series 5 units right"?

2) Since
$$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n \geq 0} x^n,$$
then isn't the above statement saying that
$$\sum_{n \geq 0} x^k = \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{4^{n+1}}(x-5)^n$$
While I concede may actually be equal, it sure doesn't look that way (and when I tried subtracting them on Wolframalpha, it didn't understand). *Is that right?*

3) *Why is it wrong to find the series* for $f$ about 5 as
$$\frac 1{1-(x-5)} = \sum_{n \geq 0} (x-5)^n?$$

And please answer all the other questions (that I can't seem to articulate) about this solution.

Answer (score 1):

The issue that is common to your first two questions is that of convergence.  The book's solution gives a power series that converges if $|x-5|$ is small, i.e. $x$ is close to $5$.  It differs from the series $\sum x^n$ because that series converges if $|x-0|$ is small, i.e. $x$ is close to $0$.  For example, if you take $x=4.9$, then the one series converges but other diverges.  Hence, they are equal as formal series, but they are not necessarily equal for particular values of $x$.  If both converge, then they are equal.  :-)

As for the third question, your series is a perfectly good series that converges if $|x-5|$ is small.  However, it converges to $\frac{1}{6-x}$,  not $\frac{1}{1-x}$.

Comment: Still digesting this and trying to understand it.